# Replace match and ignore certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace `{r-group1}` with "REPLACED" but leave the `,` where it is.

So, the string

```
var string = "{r-group1, }foo bar"
```

should output: "REPLACED, foo bar"

Using a [negative lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/xM2sY2/1), I tried adding a preceding `(?![,])` group to leave the comma alone:

```
var replaced = string.replace(^(?:(?![,]){r-group1\})+$, 'REPLACED');
```

But it returns the same string. There are no matches to replace.

The same goes for a preceding comma:

```
var string = "foo bar{r-, group1}"
```

This should output: "foo bar, REPLACED"

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\{r-group1,[^,]*}(.+)`  https://regex101.com/r/RunuHv/1/

Comment: If I use `.replace` javascript function: `var b = string.replace(/\{r-group1,[^,]*}(.+)/g, 'REPLACED');` it replaces the entire string with "REPLACED". Also, on that site, it's replacing "foo bar" and not the {r- group1}

Comment: You could use the capturing group `$1` in the replacement ``$1, REPLACED``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the replacement without a lookahead. You could match the curly braces and the content that comes before and after it except a comma using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^,}]+` and capture the comma with optional whitespace chars in a capturing group.

In the replacement use the capturing groups `$1REPLACED$2`

Credits to [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) for the updated pattern.

```
{r-(,?\s*)[^,}]+(,?\s*)}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OYMTpm/1)

```js
const regex = /{r-(,?\s*)[^,}]+(,?\s*)}/g;
const str = `{r-group1, }foo bar`;
const subst = `$1REPLACED$2`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why do I need the `$1,`? Firstly, how does the `$1` work and secondly why do you need to add another comma after it if you're skipping replacement on the comma anyway?

Comment: @Growler In this case the pattern matches the comma and will be removed from the string. What is captured in the group is used as the replacement. In the second example you can also match what you want to remove and add `, REPLACED` after it. In this link, the match is highlighted in blue, and the group in green https://regex101.com/r/IEnVrx/1

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue is your solution seems to assume I know where to add the comma. I don't. The input string _comes_ with the comma in the `{}` brackets and I need to replace everything inside the brackets except for where the comma is. Another dynamic input string could be `"{r- salutation1, }como estas{r- , group1}?"`. In this case I'd need the result to be `"REPLACED, como estas, REPLACED?"` where "REPLACED" will be some dynamic string I add

Comment: @Growler You don't want the curly braces in the replacement? And there is only a single comma between the curly braces?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace everything within the curly braces, including the curly braces, with some replacement string... (like "REPLACED"), but leave the location of the comma where it is.

Comment: @Growler Like this? https://regex101.com/r/6g12jA/1 You match what you want to delete and capture in the group what you want to keep, which is the comma and is in  `$1`

Comment: I think that's right, but that seems to depend on the comma being _after_, when the original question says the comma can also be before the word in brackets. I.e., `foo bar{r-, group1 }` gives result `foo barREPLACED,` when it should be `foo bar, REPLACED`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205325/discussion-between-growler-and-the-fourth-bird).